# In a HTML table using Angular, and a button to open a modal displays on each row, it always displays the first of the element list

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I present a table with customers, when clicking on the button "Details", 
supposed to open a modal that displays the **selected** customer details, but the modal always displays the **FIRST** CUSTOMER of the list

```
  <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Nom</th>
          <th>Prénom</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


          <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">

            <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.firstname}}</td>

            <td>

              <!-- VIEW button -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" 
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal">Détails</button>

              <!-- displays the details modal -->
              <app-details-customer [customer] = customer></app-details-customer>

          </tr>


      </tbody>
  </table>
```

### Here is the modal HTML code of the content of the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="view-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Détails d'un client</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
      
              <!-- First name -->   
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">Id:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" 
                          id="firstname" [(ngModel)]="customer.id" name="id" readonly>
              </div>
    
              <!-- First name -->   
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Firstname" 
                          id="firstname" [(ngModel)]="customer.firstname" name="firstname">
              </div>
              <!-- Last name -->
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Lastname" 
                            id="lastname" [(ngModel)]="customer.lastname" name="lastname">
              </div>  
          
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
      
          </div>
      
          <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
              
    </div>
```

### and here is the typescript code for the details modal

```
import { Component, Injectable, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details-customer',
  templateUrl: './details-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details-customer.component.css']
})

// @Injectable()
export class DetailsCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() customer: Customer;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**Could you help me to solve this issue ?**
**Many thanks in advance**

Comment: Can we see what your customer data structure looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You have a  that is not being closed in the HTML that could be causing the issue. Try

```
<tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.firstname}}</td>

    <td>
        <!-- VIEW button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal">Détails</button>
        <!-- displays the details modal -->
        <app-details-customer [customer]=customer></app-details-customer>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I tryied using HTML code but it doen't help
2. customer.ts is:

```
export class Customer {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: number;
    address: string
}
```